# Conditions for series rearrangement

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_{n,k})_{n, k \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb C$ be a series satisfying

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left| \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n,k}\right| \lt \infty
$$
and
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left|a_{n,k}\right| \lt \infty \qquad \forall n\in \mathbb N.
$$
Does this imply that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n,k}$ converges with
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n,k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n,k},
$$
ie. the order of summation can be rearranged?

In a lecture a proof was given (at least I think so!) for the case that instead of the first condition above the series satisfies
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty |a_{n,k}| \lt \infty.
$$
(Am I right that this last condition itself is enough to justify switching the order because of the Fubini theorem?)

Can the series be rearranged in general or is there a (nasty) counter example?

Comment: I know the condition to be summable as $$\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\sum_{k,j=0}^n |a_{j,k}|<\infty$$ where the index means that $0\le k,j\le n$

Comment: I think you mean [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left| \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n,k}\right| \lt \infty
$$
is not sufficient, see the counter-example below.

Define a serie $\{a_{n,k}\}$, where
$$
a_{n,k} = \cases{\frac{1}{n^2}-1 & if $n=k$, \\ 1 & if $n \ne k, k=1$, \\ 0 & else.}
$$
Then we can easily verify that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left| \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n,k}\right| = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} -1 \lt \infty,$$ but $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left|\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n,k}\right| = \infty.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to verify the counter example (although I think the series should star with $n=1$ and $k=1$.)

Comment: You're right, I confused myself with the notations. But it's not essential, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the double series

$$1-1+0+0+0+0 +\cdots$$ $$0+2-2+0+0+0+\cdots $$ $$0+0+3-3+0+0 +\cdots $$ $$0+0+0 +4 -4+ 0 + \cdots$$ $$0+ 0+0+0+5-5+\cdots$$

where of course we continue the rows in this pattern on out to $\infty.$ We have absolutely convergent series in each row and column. But the interated double series sums to $0$ in one order, and $\infty$ in the opposite order.

Comment: This is also a nice example. (…and probably both quicker to check and easier to remember than the accepted answer.)