# Conditions for changing the order of summation in $ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am reading a lecture note [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2018/lecture-notes/MIT6_436JF18_lec05.pdf) and it says the following:

> If we have a doubly indexed family of nonnegative numbers $a_{ij}, \
>  i, \ j \in \mathbb{N}$ and if either (i) the numbers are nonnegative,
>   or (ii) the sum $\sum_{(i,j)} a_{ij}$ is absolutely convergent, then
>
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} =  \sum_{j=1}^\infty
>  \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \sum_{(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}^2} a_{ij}$$
>
> More important, we stress that the first equality need not hold in the
>   absence of conditions (i) and (ii).

I am not sure why the last comment holds regarding the first equality where we change the order of the summation. Is there any well known counter-example?

Comment: I removed the [tag:probability-theory] tag. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Comment: There seems to be a redundant condition:  "a family of **nonnegative numbers** $a_{ij}$" must always satisfy condition (i).

Comment: See my example at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006993/conditions-for-series-rearrangement/2007071#2007071