# Countably infinite sum as an integral?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357445/interchange-finite-and-infinite-sum) post, the first answer states that a countably infinite summation can always be taken as an integral. Why is this? Is there some general formula that can turn any countably infinite summation into an integral?

Comment: How far do you know in measure theory ?

Comment: provided the series converges, otherwise there's not much point to it

Comment: @nicomezi I am currently on additivity for step functions and the lebesgue monotone convergence theorem. I did study measure theory a few years ago but didn't use it in the meantime so I remember little of it, hence why I'm going back through it rigorously now.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Assuming the series converges then, what does this conversion operation look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sum $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent, then yes: you can view the sequence $(a_0,a_1,\cdots)$ as a function $f$ on the measure space $(\Bbb N,\mu)$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure, and $\sum a_n$ as the integral $\int_\Bbb N f\,\mathrm d\mu$.